# Can "legacy" .NET projects also use the new NuGet 3 features?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

The new NuGet version fixes lots of problems (e.g. transitive dependency capabilities, dependency resolution at build time, single packages repository cache, etc.).

However I could only test it with the ASP.NET vNext and UWP projects.

Will these new features also be available for "legacy" projects (e.g. full .NET 4.5/4.6 projects, WPF, etc.)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**As of 8/19/2015**, it seems that the new features are **not supported** for "legacy" projects but may be added later. According to the [NuGet documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/ProjectJson-Intro):

> project.json is mandatory for UWP apps and ASP.NET 5 apps, is
>   optional for PCLs, and currently is not fully supported on other
>   project systems.

and

> Starting from Visual Studio 2015, several project types are utilizing
>   this technology, **with more to follow in the future**.
>
> 1.Universal Windows Platform managed apps (UWP).
>
> 2.Portable class libraries (PCL).
>
> 3.ASP.NET 5 applications.